# what are the minimum steps to deploy slickgrid with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slickgrid

node v12.20.2
npm v6.14.11

not much in the way of node.js examples out there for [slickgrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid).

**EDIT:**

using the actions below, ive managed to get slickgrid to load without errors, but theres no grid and the column names, then data, are just enumerated vertically like a list.

```sh
$ npm install slickgrid
$ npm install jquery
$ npm install jquery-ui-dist
```

then i had to copy `jquery.event.drag-2.3.0.js` from the `lib` directory of [the repository](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) to my project folder.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var jQuery = require('jquery');
        require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui');
        require('./jquery.event.drag-2.3.0');
        require('slickgrid/slick.core');
        require('slickgrid/slick.grid');
                
        function test() {
            var columns = [
                {id: "column1", name: "Column1", field: "column1"},
                {id: "column2", name: "Column2", field: "column2"}
            ];

            var data = [
                {
                    column1: "Test1",
                    column2: "Test2"
                }
            ];

            var options = {}

            new Slick.Grid("#mydiv", data, columns, options);
        }

        window.onload = test();
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that seems wrong which is probably not helping

1. Your `require('slickgrid')` is wrong, it should be `require('slickgrid/slick.grid')` and it should be outside of the function on the first couple lines of imports.
2. The other thing you're missing is jQueryUI import, I use it with the minified dist package from npm with `require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui')`
3. You also have to instantiate it and you're not, you need to call `new Slick.Grid(...)` and you cannot alias that, it really has to `Slick.Grid` because that is what is defined in the jQuery namespace
4. this last step is an extra but if you have linting issues, you might need to make `Slick` as an available global variable in your eslint to avoid red squiggly, in my case with TypeScript I do it this way `declare const Slick: any;` to avoid linting errors.

If you still have problem, you can check my TypeScript implementation [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/master/packages/vanilla-bundle/src/components/slick-vanilla-grid-bundle.ts) that is used for my [Slickgrid-Universal](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal) library (which is wrapper on top of the `6pac/SlickGrid` fork)

Comment: question adapted using the info you provided.

Comment: well in your updated question, you're completely missing the CSS styling for the grid, I can't provide you mine because mine are specific for my libs but if you go to any of the SlickGrid Examples, you'll see it references multiple CSS styling files which you are missing